# How to display such a graph using plotly

Tags: python, database, dataframe, plotly, plotly-dash

[I have a dataset like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoYLX.png)

[i want to display a graph like this using plotly (dash)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSs5M.png)

Comment: data as text - it's a stacked bar

Comment: @RobRaymond data can be converted with OCR :)

Comment: But yes, @Sohibjon, you should include data as text so that we could answer more easily. Also you should add the image directly in your question to get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Plotly Express `bar` chart. But you will first have to transform your dataframe from a wide to long format.

There is a complete example with your data:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px


data = """Director,Accountant,Foo,Texawaka,MeHenokep,Wed nosap,Programmer,Cy-wed
0,0,90,19,5,2,0,0
0,0,84,19,7,2,0,1
0,0,84,19,9,4,0,1
0,0,90,19,9,5,0,1
0,0,92,19,9,6,0,1
0,0,92,19,9,41,0,1
0,0,138,81,11,47,0,1
0,17,338,237,20,57,0,4
1,155,412,272,52,116,0,5
6,156,454,282,51,121,1,20
15,156,506,307,53,122,10,42
19,156,581,310,59,123,13,77
20,156,612,311,61,123,16,78
20,156,624,314,60,123,16,78
20,133,660,359,59,123,16,78
19,128,703,398,59,123,16,78
19,127,713,398,59,117,16,78
19,119,561,315,59,103,16,78
17,10,533,249,59,93,15,78
16,1,500,212,58,85,13,78
6,1,467,192,58,81,9,72
1,0,404,171,50,38,4,13
0,0,365,171,37,19,2,6
0,0,357,171,30,9,1,4
"""

# Create pandas.DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=",").reset_index()

# Convert DataFrame from wide to long format
df_long = pd.melt(df, id_vars="index", var_name='position', value_name='value')

# Plot 
fig = px.bar(df_long, x="index", y="value", color="position")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- your data as an image means it cannot be used in an answer.  Majority of code is generating a representative sample dataset
- it's a straight forward bar plot.  Have set **dtick** so there is a label against every value in xaxis.  Have re-positioned legend

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

ROWS = 24
careers = [
    "Director",
    "Accountant",
    "Programmer",
    "Technician",
    "Office Manager",
    "Designer",
]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        c: a[1][np.where(a[0] >= 0)[0][0] : np.where(a[0] == 0)[0][0] + ROWS]
        for c, a in zip(
            careers,
            [
                np.unique(
                    np.random.normal(
                        ROWS / 2, (ROWS / 2) / 2.33, random.randint(500, 1000)
                    ).astype(int),
                    return_counts=True,
                )
                for _ in careers
            ],
        )
    }
)

px.bar(df, y=df.columns).update_layout(
    xaxis={"dtick": 1, "title":""},
    yaxis={"title":""},
    legend={"yanchor": "bottom", "xanchor": "left", "x": 0, "y": -.2, "orientation": "h", "title":""},
)
```

[image]